# Getting max from dictionary key substrings

Tags: python

given is a dictionary containing interface configuration like this:

```
{"1/1":{"speed": 100, "duplex":...}, "1/2":{"speed": 100, "duplex":...}, ... "2/1":{"speed": 100, "duplex":...}
```

The first identifier in "2/1" is for the chassis (2) and second for the interface (1). Each chassis contains X number of interfaces and I need the number of chassis (in 1/1, 2/1, 3/1 it would be three) and the number of interfaces in each chassis (in 1/1, 1/2, ... 1/48 it would be 48).
I dont want to loop through the interfaces too much because there are quiete a lot.

Full dictionary:

````
interfaces:
1: {tagged: Array(4)}
1/1: {adminState: false, lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100'}
1/2: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '100'}
1/3: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '900'}
1/4: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
1/5: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
1/6: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
1/7: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
1/8: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
1/9: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
1/10: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
1/11: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
1/12: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
1/13: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
1/14: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
1/15: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
1/16: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
1/17: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
1/18: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
1/19: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
1/20: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
1/21: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
1/22: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
1/23: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
1/24: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
1/25: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
1/26: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
1/27: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
1/28: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
1/29: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
1/30: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
1/31: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
1/32: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
1/33: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
1/34: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
1/35: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
1/36: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
1/37: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
1/38: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
1/39: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
1/40: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
1/41: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
1/42: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
1/43: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
1/44: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
1/45: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
1/46: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
1/47: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
1/48: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
1/49: {alias: '->sw01-1/1/26', linkagg: '1', trap: true}
1/50: {lldp: false}
2/1: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
2/2: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
2/3: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
2/4: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
2/5: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
2/6: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
2/7: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
2/8: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
2/9: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
2/10: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
2/11: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
2/12: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
2/13: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
2/14: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
2/15: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
2/16: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
2/17: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
2/18: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
2/19: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
2/20: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
2/21: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
2/22: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
2/23: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
2/24: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
2/25: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
2/26: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
2/27: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
2/28: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
2/29: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
2/30: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
2/31: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
2/32: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
2/33: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
2/34: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
2/35: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
2/36: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
2/37: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
2/38: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
2/39: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
2/40: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
2/41: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
2/42: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
2/43: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
2/44: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
2/45: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
2/46: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
2/47: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
2/48: {lldp: false, loopback: true, mobile: true, speed: '100', untagged: '200'}
2/49: {lldp: false}
2/50: {alias: '->sw01-2/1/26', linkagg: '1', trap: true}
3/1: {untagged: '700'}```
````

Comment: The logic behind max values is not clear. How did you arrive to `24` and `48`

Comment: Where are 3 and 24 in the given dictionary?

Comment: Please be clear. I think you are using some logic that may not be general knowledge. So edit the question to include all relevant details

Comment: Youre criticism is justified. I find it hard to explain the logic. hopefully I did better in the edit this time.

Comment: Can you at least provide a full (working) dictionary to work with, that has the different chassis you are referring to?

Comment: @JeffUK Had it like that before but the problem is, that in other addressing cases I need the interfaces at this position and with this name.

Comment: what you expect the output? and isn't using `chassis/interface` for key value if wrong way structuring the ADAS data? you could use something like `{<chassis_no>:{ <interface_data>:{ <that data>}}, .....} somethign like this  .. but if this is already defined structure than nothing can be done. so now can you tell what you expect from this dictionary an sample output maybe ?

Comment: Do you realise that your dictionary keys are floats, not strings. And have a significant chance of collisions?  i.e. when you assign 2/4 it will over-write 1/2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict as dd
result = dd(max)
x = {'1/1': {}, '1/2': {}, '1/3': {}, '1/4': {}, '1/5': {}, '1/6': {}, '1/7': {}, '1/8': {}, '1/9': {}, 
...  '2/1': {}, '2/2': {}, '2/3': {}, '2/4': {}, '2/5': {}, '2/6': {}, '2/7': {}, '2/8': {}, '2/9': {}, '2/10': {}, '2/11': {}, '2/12': {}, '2/13': {}, '2/14': {}, '2/15': {}, '2/16': {}, '2/17': {}, '2/18': {}, '2/19': {}, '2/20': {}, '2/21': {}, '2/22': {}, '2/23': {}, '2/24': {}, '2/25': {}, '2/26': {}, '2/27': {}, '2/28': {}, '2/29': {}, '2/30': {}, '2/31': {}, '2/32': {}, '2/33': {}, '2/34': {}, '2/35': {}, '2/36': {}, '2/37': {},
...  '2/38': {}, '2/39': {}, '2/40': {}, '2/41': {}, '2/42': {}, '2/43': {}, '2/44': {}, '2/45': {}, '2/46': {}, '2/47': {}, '2/48': {}, '2/49': {},
...  '3/1': {}, '3/2': {}, '3/3': {}, '3/4': {}, '3/5': {}, '3/6': {}, '3/7': {}, '3/8': {}, '3/9': {}, '3/10': {}}
  
for k in x.keys():
    if '/' in k:
        a, b = k.split('/')
        result[a]=b

print(result)
# defaultdict(<built-in function max>, {'1': '9', '2': '49', '3': '10'})
```

Comment: This works perfect and was just what I was looking for. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Storing that information as a substring is always going to mean you're giving yourself more work.

You could just use a nested dict `interfaces = {interface:{chassis:{"speed": 100, "duplex":...},..},..}` the use len() to find out how many chassis are in each interface.

```
interfaces = {1:{1:{"speed": 100},2:{"speed": 100}},
              2:{1:{"speed": 200}}}
for interface, chassis_dict in interfaces.items():
    print(interface, len(chassis_dict))
```

Or an interface object that has a list of all supported chassis within.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to use the 1/1 format since there are four more places where this addressing of the interfaces is easier and just the max count of chassis and interfaces where it isnt. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

```py
from itertools import groupby

data = {"1/1":{}, "1/2":{}, "2/1":{}, "2/2":{}, "2/3":{}}

c_i = [k.split('/') for k in data.keys()]
grouped = {k: list(g) for k, g in groupby(c_i, key=lambda x: x[0])}

print('Count chassis:', len(grouped))
print('Count interface for chassis #1:', len(grouped['1']))
print('Count interface for chassis #2:', len(grouped['2']))
```

**Output:**

```
Count chassis: 2
Count interface for chassis #1: 2
Count interface for chassis #2: 3
```

Comment: If you have keys like `1` without slash, then you'll have to filter them out. Add `c_i = list(filter(lambda x: len(x) == 2, c_i))`

Comment: This could also be a good solution, thanks for getting into it.